# Getting rid of empty select menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, select, menu

I have searched and searched. I can't find how to remove an empty select menu at http://propelyourteam.com

**CSS**

```
.select-menu, .select {
display: none;}

.menu-main-container {
position: relative;}
```

**Menu Php**

```
<div class="header-right">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header', 'menu_id' => 'nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav-top', 'container' => '', 'container-class' => '', ) ); ?>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `custom.js` file on line 69 you're creating what looks like a mobile menu using the Mobile Menu plugin.  You can find more information on how to use that plugin [here](https://github.com/mambows/mobilemenu).  (It needs to have some parameters passed to the function in order to properly select your navigation menu items).

However if you don't want to use this plugin you can remove line 69 and would probably also want to stop it from being included in your `functions.php`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked great.